# Cicle around prompt not working

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to make a cicle around **prompt**. The object of prompt - grab custumer input value and push it to **eval** function for making a result (converting whole string to digits with math operators('+', '*', etc...)).

The appointment of circle - is to check the result of **eval** function and if eval(a) != digit -> repeat **prompt** each time when user input in **prompt** non-digit values ('a', ',', etc...)

The other part of code only for catching an errors.

```
do {
    var a = prompt('your number', '10-2*4');
} while (eval(a) != 'number');

try {
    console.log( eval(a) ); //must display 2
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e); 
}
```

Comment: It's called a "loop", not a "circle".

Comment: `eval(a) != 'number'` makes no sense. That condition can only be satisfied once you enter the string `"number"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test of `eval(s) != 'number'` should be something like `typeof eval(+s) !='number'`

You could make it a recursive function:

```js
function doPrompt(){  
   try {
     // if this line throws error will go to catch
     var res = eval(prompt('your number', '10-2*4'));
     // do it again if we don't have a number, or return number
     return typeof +res ==='number' ? +res : doPrompt()
   }catch(e){
     return doPrompt();
   }
};

var res =  doPrompt();

console.log(res)
```

This would be a lot cleaner using an `<input>` instead which would allow for better ability to display errors to user. Using `prompt` is not very flexible